# map multiple Card components with Menu

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of items and for each item, I want to display a Card component. Each Card has a pop up Menu. I am having trouble opening just the specific clicked Menu to open. My code opens all Menus together. Here is the code snippet.

Second issue is that I get a warning about not being able to having a button within a button. I make the Card Header clickable, and then I have the Menu. What's the correct way to implement this in order to avoid the warning?

```
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)

  const handleMenuClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget)
  }

return (
  { 
    props.items.map( (k, i) => (       
      <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea onClick={(e) => handleRedirect(e)}> 
        <MyMenu key={i} index={i} anchor={anchorEl} />           
        <CardHeader                
           action={
             <IconButton id={i} aria-label="settings" onClick={handleMenuClick}>
                <MoreVertIcon />
             </IconButton>
           }
           title={k.title}
           subheader={getTimestamp(k._id)}
         />

       </CardActionArea>
```

MyMenu code:

```
const MyMenu = ( { index, anchor } ) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    //setAnchorEl({[e.target.id]: anchor})

    if (anchor!==null) {
      if (index===anchor.id)
        setAnchorEl({[index]: anchor})
    }
  }, [anchor, index])

  const handleRedirect = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    //history.push('/item/'+ id)
  }

  const handleClose = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    setAnchorEl({[e.target.id]: null})    
  };

  return (
    <Menu
      id={index}
      anchorEl={anchorEl[index]}
      open={Boolean(anchorEl[index])}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleRedirect(e)}>Read</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={(e) => handleRedirect(e)}>Edit</MenuItem>

    </Menu>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below.

```
const handleMenuClick = (e, setter) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  setter(e.currentTarget)
}

return (
  { 
      props.items.map( (k, i) => {

      const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)

     return (
     <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea onClick={(e) => handleRedirect(e)}> 
        <MyMenu key={i} index={i} anchor={anchorEl} />           
        <CardHeader                
           action={
             <IconButton id={i} aria-label="settings" onClick={(e) => handleMenuClick(e, setAnchorEl)}>
                <MoreVertIcon />
             </IconButton>
           }
           title={k.title}
           subheader={getTimestamp(k._id)}
         />

       </CardActionArea>
     </Card> 
     )
```

Basically in above, you are creating separate state for each mapped object. And I tweaked the click event to accept a `setState` callback.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sandy. I was able to resolve this by moving this code to the parent component

```
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState({})

  const handleMenuClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    setAnchorEl({[e.currentTarget.id]: e.currentTarget})
  }

...

<IconButton id={i} onClick={handleMenuClick}>
```